# Not sure what the "A" stands for in this gMock example

Tags: googlemock

```
EXPECT_CALL(foo, Describe(A<const char*>()))
    .InSequence(s2)
    .WillOnce(Return("dummy"));
```

In the above sample text, the parameter for the Describe method I don't understand.
It looks like a class name then a template, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it's a [wildcard matcher](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Wildcard), meaning that the expectation will be satisfied if the mocked function `string Foo::Describe(const char* name);` is called with any value for `name`.

Comment: The difference from using "_" instead of "A", is that the type is specific. That way, you can choose between overloaded methods. (That it looks like a template class is just because google mock is implemented using template classes.)